# Arranging numbers for a given sum

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose I have numbers the $\{0,1,2,3\}$ in how many ways can one arrange them
so the sum would be equal to 5?
For instance, 
$$
\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 1 & 2 & 2 \\
1 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
1 & 2 & 0 & 2\\ 
1 & 2 & 2 & 0\\
0& 2 & 2 & 1\\
\vdots &  &  &  \\
2 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots
\end{array}
$$
As you can see I am looking for ALL (including permutations) possible combinations (such that the
sum of each row is 5). I was wondering if this can be represented by binomial coefficients?

*side note:* This is just a simplified example, I would want to then generalise such that sum of each row would be (0 to 8), i.e. In how many ways one can arrange 0,1,2,3 so the sum would be 0 and 1 and ... 8. But I wanted to know how this works first for a given sum.

Comment: Must there always be 4 summands?

Comment: Yes this is important to have only 4 empty places to fill.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe your question would be my very last step. But for now I need to understand how the basics of this works.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics) in conjunction with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle

Comment: As an aside, if you do not mind using technology to assist in solving, you could simply look at the coefficient of $x^5$ in the expansion of $(1+x+x^2+x^3)^4=1+4x+10x^2+\dots+40x^5+44x^6+\dots+10x^{10}+4x^{11}+x^{12}$

Comment: @JMoravitz oh wow this solved even my side note question. So I suppose in general if I have n columns then to see how many ways are there for each given sum I shall have: $(x^0+x^1+\cdots+x^n)^n$ and look at coefficients? does this method have a formal name in literature? It looks like a generating function of some sort.

Comment: @William yes, it is a generating function.

Comment: but is it a well known one? so i can read about it more in the literature?

Comment: It is indeed a generating function.  As for if it is well known, the problem you describe certainly is.  You are counting [restricted weak compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) (*restricted on number of parts and weak, allowing zero*) and the generating function for this problem is well known (*though probably has not received a special name*).  It is not however the recommended approach for if you were to try to calculate this by hand.  If you were to do that, I would recommend Idea's answer for the very small cases and Interstellar's for the larger cases.

Comment: "Yes this is important to have only 4 empty places to fill. " Then I suggest you actually state that in the question.  That is one heck of a condition and it is stated or implied exactly nowhere in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us consider the Diophantine Equation $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 = 5$ with integer solutions. We place the restriction that for all $i$ we have $0\le x_i \le 3$. This is a well-known problem. First, we consider the case with no upper bound, then we subtract the cases where an upper bound is violated.

We consider the case when $0\le x_i$ (with no upper bound). There are $\dbinom{5+4-1}{5} = \dbinom{8}{5}$ ways to generate this sum. Now, we use Inclusion/Exclusion to subtract off sums that violate the upper bound of 3. It is not possible for two of the summands to be at least 4 (since we have the lower bound of zero already). So, only one upper bound can be violated at a time, but any one of the four will be violated. So, we assume $x_1\ge 4$ while $0\le x_2,x_3,x_4$. Solutions with these lower bounds are in one-to-one correspondence with solutions to the Diophantine equation with $y_1=x_1-4$, $y_2=x_2, y_3=x_3,y_4=x_4$ and $0\le y_i$. Now, we have $5=x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 = y_1+4+y_2+y_3+y_4$ so $y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4 = 1$. This has $\dbinom{1+4-1}{1} = \dbinom{4}{1}$ solutions. Since any of the upper bounds could be violated in this way, we have the total number of solutions (with both upper and lower bounds) as:

$$\dbinom{8}{5}-4\dbinom{4}{1} = 40$$

Answer (score 1):

> If you have n distinct objects and you want to make all possible arrangements out of them, then there are n! ways to do so.
>   But, say if r1 out of n objects are of one kind, r2 of other kind, and so on till rk of other kind, then, total possible arrangements of n objects would be:
>   $$ \frac{n!}{r1!r2!....rk!} $$

For getting sum 5 using only 4 summands(repetitions allowed), you have following choices:
**3200, 3110, 2210 and 2111.**

For 3200 case: 0 is repeated twice. So, total arrangements are $ \frac{4!}{2!} $  =12 ways
For 3110 and 2210 case: proceed similarly. $ \frac{4!}{2!} $    =12 ways
For 2111 case: $ \frac{4!}{3!} $  =4 ways

So, total ways are **12+12+12+4=40.**

Comment: This technique, although correct, is not easily generalizable to larger cases.  What if we instead were wanting to find all ways that $100$ summands in the range $\{0,1,\dots,50\}$ added up to $1000$?  I certainly wouldn't advise anyone try to list out all possible cases there.

Comment: Sure. But @William wanted to know how it works. Hence i used basic listing method.